# How to access SDcard clicking on a html link through javascript..?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, browser

**EDIT:**

Basically i want an Html file embeded with javascript or Jquery that can access SDCARD contents directly,while opening it in a browser(since it is an html file).Since it is accessible VIA an activity i have posted code for it,But i want to hit SDCARD docs directly rather than from an android app.

**Posted:**

I have a HTML file stored in Sdcard which consist of a code including javascript to access SDcard contents.

I have tested the same code from an Activity and webView and its working fine,But i want that the `content to be displayed on directly clicking on HTML Link` rather than through an activity.

Is there any way to write `Android permissions in HTML CODE`.or how would i access it directly using HTML,JavaSCRIPT or JQUERY etc..

The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cordova</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

     var edt=document.getElementById("")


    function getFileSystem() {
        window.LocalFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem
                || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

        alert("====== hey its me===");

        window.requestFileSystem(1, 0, onFileSystemSuccessUpload, fail);    
       }

    function fail() {
        console.log("Error getting system");
    }

    function onFileSystemSuccessUpload(fileSystem) {
        // get directory entry through root and access all the folders
        var directoryReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();

        // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
        directoryReader.readEntries(successReader, fail);

    }

    function successReader(entries) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            //alert(entries[i].name);
            document.write("<p>" + entries[i].name+"</p>");
            //document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "" + entries[i].name;
            if (entries[i].isDirectory == true) {
                var directoryReaderIn = entries[i].createReader();
                directoryReaderIn.readEntries(successReader, fail);

            }

        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <a onclick="getFileSystem()" href="javascript:void(0);">Click here to View File System</a>



</body>
</html>
```

cordova.js is kept in parallel directory as of html file../

Answer (score 0):

AS i know, due to security issues, browser wont let you do it(direct access to local drive)

Comment: but how would a browsers downloads a file directly to internal or external storage..? The browser must be having permissions to access the SDCARD...??

Comment: because that is an application behavior, your html,javascript is not allow to do that due for security issues, else everybody can access local file and upload to steal info.